# How to display list of all other users with details from firebase excluding currently logged in user?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This code currently displays all users including the logged user accessing this data for display (Search in the future).

**Typescript:**

```ts
   public ngOnInit(): void {

    if (this._auth$.authenticated) {
      //=================================================//
      // Get all users Except current user
      //=============================================//
        this.users = this.all_data;
        console.log(this.users);
      }
 }
```

**Html:**

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 offset-md-3">
        <section class="centered-form">
          <img id="displayImage" [src]="user.ProfileImage.image" alt="profile Image">
          <h5>Full Name: {{user.profile.fullName}}</h5>
          <p>
          <br/>Age: {{user.profile.age}}
       </p>
    </section>
```

Comment: you have the current Logged in user save somewhere

Answer (score 3):

Somthing like this

```ts
this.users = this.all_data.filter(user => !isAuthenticated(user));
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something a little different with my code and it worked. I will post the answer in case someone might look for this. Your code assumes that I have a function that takes a user. But my code has the id of the current user already.

Answer (score 0):

So I did something that worked for me.
Looped through each data object within the array and checked for the key then saved it to a new array before returning it to the view.

```
 this.all_data.subscribe(users => {
    var data = [];
    users.forEach(user => {
      if (user.$key !== this._auth$.id) {
        console.log(user);
        data.push(user);
      }
    });
    this.users = data;
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your full code? This will helpful for me

Comment: Hey, I have solved it already. That code works but NOT well optimized for the usage I needed so I changed it. So thank you.